# Getting the "JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-transition-group

I am working on an internal software for my company, and my supervisor wants a clean up the the sharp transition that usually occurs with react-router. What I found was react-transition-group. I added it to my project, and attempted to copy what was done via http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/with-react-router but when I did, I got the following error: "var Component: JSX.Element" :: "JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)"

Currently, I have been looking to updates for both react or typescript, attempted to change name from 'Component' in case it was an issue of overlap.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Container,
  Button
} from 'reactstrap'
import NavMenu from './components/nav/NavMenu'
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/pages/Home'
import AccountInfo from './components/pages/AccountInfo/AccountInfo'
import LeaveRequests from './components/pages/LeaveRequests/LeaveRequests'
import PersonnelView from       './components/pages/PersonnelViews/PersonnelView'
import { IAppState } from './interfaces/state/state'
import { Summary401k } from './components/pages/HR/401PreTaxCash/401kSummary'
// eslint-disable-next-line
import authStore from './stores/AuthStore'
import { CashBalanceSummary } from './components/pages/HR/401PreTaxCash/CashBalanceSummary';
import { MarketPlaceCoverage } from     './components/pages/HR/HealthBenefits/MarketPlaceCoverage';
import { PreTaxSummary } from './components/pages/HR/HealthBenefits/PreTaxSummary';
import { UHCPrescription } from './components/pages/HR/HealthBenefits/UHCPrescription';
import { DiscriminationPolicy } from './components/pages/HR/OnboardingDocuments/DiscriminationPolicy';
import { EmployeeHandbook } from './components/pages/HR/OnboardingDocuments/EmployeeHandbook';
import { Holidays } from './components/pages/HR/OnboardingDocuments/Holidays';
import { RemoteWork } from './components/pages/HR/OnboardingDocuments/RemoteWork';
import { SensitiveInformation } from './components/pages/HR/OnboardingDocuments/SensitiveInformation';
import { VacationLeavePolicy } from './components/pages/HR/OnboardingDocuments/VacationLeavePolicy';
import { Timekeeping } from './components/pages/HR/Timekeeping/Timekeeping';
import { TimekeepingLeave } from './components/pages/HR/Timekeeping/TimekeepingLeave';
import { UHCMedical } from './components/pages/HR/HealthBenefits/UHCMedical';
import HRHome from './components/pages/HR/HrHome';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

export default class App extends React.Component<{}, IAppState> {
  private _logout: any;

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      AuthState: {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        jwtToken: "",
        pId: -1
      },
      logout: false
    }
  }

  render() {

    const routes = [
      { path: '/', name: 'Home', Component: <Home authCallback={this.authCallback} isLoggedIn={this.state.AuthState.isLoggedIn} authenticatedFunction={this.authenticatedFunction} unauthenticatedFunction={this.unauthenticatedFunction} /> },
      { path: '/account', name: 'Account Info', Component: <AccountInfo jwtToken={this.state.AuthState.jwtToken} pId={this.state.AuthState.pId} /> },
      { path: '/personnel', name: 'Personnel', Component: <PersonnelView jwtToken={this.state.AuthState.jwtToken} /> },
      { path: '/hrhome', name: 'HR Home', Component: <HRHome /> },
      { path: '/401ksummary', name: '401(k) Summary', Component: <Summary401k /> },
      { path: '/cashbalancesummary', name: 'Cash Balance Summary', Component: <CashBalanceSummary /> },
      { path: '/marketplacecoverage', name: 'Marketplace Coverage', Component: <MarketPlaceCoverage /> },
      { path: '/pretaxsummary', name: 'Pre-Tax Summary', Component: <PreTaxSummary /> },
      { path: '/uhcmedical', name: 'UHC Medical', Component: <UHCMedical /> },
      { path: '/uhcprescription', name: 'UHC Prescription', Component: <UHCPrescription /> },
      { path: '/discriminationpolicy', name: 'Discrimination Policy', Component: <DiscriminationPolicy /> },
      { path: '/employeehandbook', name: 'Employee Handbook', Component: <EmployeeHandbook /> },
      { path: '/holidays', name: 'Holidays', Component: <Holidays /> },
      { path: '/remotework', name: 'Remote Work', Component: <RemoteWork /> },
      { path: '/sensitiveinformation', name: 'Sensitive Information', Component: <SensitiveInformation /> },
      { path: '/vacationleavepolicy', name: 'Vacation Leave Policy', Component: <VacationLeavePolicy /> },
      { path: '/timekeeping', name: 'Timekeeping', Component: <Timekeeping /> },
      { path: '/timekeepingleave', name: 'Timekeeping Leave', Component: <TimekeepingLeave /> }
    ]

    return (
      <Router>
        <NavMenu logout={this._logout} isLoggedIn= {this.state.AuthState.isLoggedIn} />
        <Container>
          {
            routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
              <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
                {
                  ({ match }) => {
                    if (!Component) return null
                    return (
                      <CSSTransition
                        in={match != null}
                        timeout={300}
                        classNames="page"
                        unmountOnExit
                      >
                        <Component />
                      </CSSTransition>
                    )
                  }
                }
              </Route>
            ))
          }
        </Container>
        <Route exact path="/leaverequests" component={() => <LeaveRequests pId={this.state.AuthState.pId} jwtToken={this.state.AuthState.jwtToken} />} />
      </Router>
    );
  }

  authCallback = async (receivedAccountInfo: any) => {
    if (!this.state.AuthState.isLoggedIn) {
      if (this.state.AuthState.pId < 0) {
        this.setState({
          AuthState: {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            jwtToken: "",
            pId: 0
          }
        })
        /*
        * Store Logout

        authStore.logout()
        */
      }
      const url =  `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/personnel/id/${receivedAccountInfo.account.userName}`
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: new Headers({
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + receivedAccountInfo.jwtIdToken
        })
      })
      const id = await response.json()
      this.setState({
        AuthState: {
          isLoggedIn: true,
          jwtToken: receivedAccountInfo.jwtIdToken,
          pId: id
        }
      })
      /*
      * Store Login

      authStore.startLogin(receivedAccountInfo.jwtIdToken)
      await  authStore.fetchLogin(`api/personnel/id/${receivedAccountInfo.account.userName}`)
      console.log(authStore.getState())
      */
    }
  }

  unauthenticatedFunction = (loginFunction: any) => {
    return (
      <Button color="primary" onClick={loginFunction}>Login</Button>
    )
  }

  authenticatedFunction = (logout: any) => {
    this._logout = logout
    return (
      <Button color="primary" onClick={logout}></Button>
    )
  }
}
```

[Error via Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bv1E.png)

Comment: where exactly is this line with "var Component"

Comment: Did you try changing the variable name in `routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (` to something other than `Component`

Comment: Can you provide the entire class code? It appears to be a class, so probably related to the declaration.

Comment: When hovering over the <Component /> line (red squiggles) I get a two line comment, with a line break, of var Component and the JSX message

Comment: Updated the code to include entire class

Comment: Ahmad, I have tried using names other than Component and it did not change the effect

Comment: Do you have `@types/react` in your `package.json` (and only once)?

Comment: Yes, currently using  @types/react ^16.8.15